# Codeigniter + Redbean loading library

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm trying to use **ReadBean ORM** with **CodeIgniter** 2.0.3.
From here: [Integration with CodeIgniter](http://www.redbeanphp.com/manual/integration_with_code_igniter), I can see that there is a plugin:[Readbean-codeIngiter plugin](https://github.com/FlorianH/CI-RedBean-Plugin).
I notice by readme.textfile that this is for a prior version of CI as it uses a deprecated file structure (like the plugin folder).

Now, I'd like to know how should I adapt this to work with CI 2.0.3.
[Here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_200.html) says that plugins should be helpers now, but couldn't get this work. Probably because I'm a newbie in CI, got confused with all this 1.7/2.0.3 - plugin/library/helper/package thing.

thanks!

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/rubensarrio/codeigniter-hmvc-redbean

Answer (score 0):

I found [a branch from michaelwills](https://github.com/michaelwills/CI-RedBean-Plugin/tree/php52/dev) that does exactly what I was looking (updating the plugin to CI2).

I tried it and seems to work (i just made a few tests inserting rows to the database).
The class to load now is called: `redbeanmodel`